# Angular Providers for Services

Tags: angular, angular-services

I learnt that in Angular we need to provide services in providers of components like `providers: [MyService]` and to access it, I need to specify in constructor:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
```

If constructor creates a property `myService` and also assigns the value passed to the constructor, why should I need to mention the service name in providers?

Comment: Because something needs to pass that value _into_ the constructor, and that something (the DI container) needs information about the things it should inject. See e.g. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection. [Parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) are a TypeScript feature, they're not specific to Angular or its DI system.

Comment: Well if you were talking about Java or C# yes you wouldn't need it because a library could easily extract what a constructor needs to be initiated and provide it. But in javascript such metadata doesn't exist and as a workaround you should provide what your constructor needs to be initialized.

Comment: In Angular, a service can have a single instance or multiple instances. That is based on how you configure/provide the service. 

When you add a service into the providers array of a module or a component, that module/component will be getting a **new instance**.

If you create a service with `providedIn: root` and don't explicitly add it to the `providers` array, you'll get the **same instance** which is available throughout the app (Singleton).

Comment: @jonrsharpe then why is required only for service ? I see for HttpClient I just provide it in constructor like http:HttpClient and I dont provide it in providers

Comment: Presumably because you're not registering that service at any higher level (root, module, ...). You don't _need_ to (and probably shouldn't) specify every dependency at the individual component level. And you don't _just_ have HttpClient in the parameter list, its module will be in an imports list somewhere (see https://angular.io/guide/http#setup-for-server-communication).

Comment: you don't need to provide HttpClient by yourself because angular do it for you when you import HttpClientModule in your app. You can see that it has HttpClient in it's list of providers https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/module.ts#L158